# Python writes the wrong thing in csv

Tags: python, csv, user-interface

Code:

```
import tkinter
import csv


def mainapp():
print ('R')

def SigUP():

U = input1.get()
P = input2.get()
R = input3.get()

def P():
    myData = [[U, P, R]]
    myFile = open('csvexample3.csv', 'w')  
    with myFile:  
            writer = csv.writer(myFile)
            writer.writerows(myData)


if U == '' or P == '' or R == '':
    print ('No')
else:
    P()

def LogIN():
U = input1.get()
P = input2.get()
R = input3.get()


main = tkinter.Tk()

realname = tkinter.Label(main, text='Real Name')
input3 = tkinter.Entry(main)
Username = tkinter.Label(main, text='Username')
input1 = tkinter.Entry(main)
Password = tkinter.Label(main, text='Password')
input2 = tkinter.Entry(main, show="*")
SigUp = tkinter.Button(main, text='Join Us Now', command=SigUP)
LogIn = tkinter.Button(main, text='Log In', command=LogIN)

input3.grid(column='2', row='1')
realname.grid(column='1', row='1')
input1.grid(column='2', row='2')
Username.grid(column='1', row='2')
input2.grid(column='2', row='3')
Password.grid(column='1', row='3')
SigUp.grid(columnspan='3', row='5')
LogIn.grid(columnspan='3', row='4')

main.mainloop()
```

In my csv file, I get this:

```
Ben4594,<function SigUP.<locals>.P at 0x101d51950>,Ben
```

I expect that my csv should look like:

```
Ben4594,Password,Ben
```

I'm Using python 3 and tkinter.

Comment: can you format your code? This one is not intended good.

Comment: Seconded, the code is not indented properly. Try indenting the whole code by four spaces and then paste it back into the question.

Comment: It would appear that where you write to the csv you are writing `P` which is actually referencing the function `P()`, not the input which you assign to the variable `P` earlier. Using proper variable and function names would avoid this issue.

Comment: Thankyou L. MacKenzie That Fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You suffer from name collision.  Look at this spot in your code:

```
U = input1.get()
P = input2.get()
R = input3.get()

def P():
#        <=============== point of interest
    myData = [[U, P, R]]
```

You *had* a simple variable **P**, but you just overwrote that with a function definition of the same name.  Thus, when you write to your file, you get the value of the function, that being the function descriptor.

Change your variable names to avoid the collision.  In general, use meaningful names, and you'll avoid this problem (and many others).

```
user_id      = input1.get()
password     = input2.get()
display_name = input3.get()

def write_user_to_file():
    myData = [[user_id, password, display_name]]
```

Also, consider using function parameters instead of global variables.